# Url Button in Grid

Tags: genexus

I have a grid that shows a business component data. One field of this table is an Url type. I don't want to show the url as text, i want show only a button that, if pressed, opens the link.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem:
I changed the visible property of the url field to 'false' and added the link to another field of the grid with this code in the 'load' event:

```
OtherFieldName.LinkTarget= '_BLANK'
OtherFieldName.Link = link(ATT:UrlFieldName)
```

I hope this can be useful for you.